# Loopback 3 File Upload is Not working on DigitalOcean Server

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, loopback

I have loopback 3 APIs hosted on DigitalOcean. I also have an API to upload images and store **filesystem**. My datasource settings are

```
"MediaFiles": {
    "name": "MediaFiles",
    "connector": "loopback-component-storage",
    "provider": "filesystem",
    "root": "./uploads"
  }
```

I have created a container named is **profile**.

When I'm trying to upload images to this container using REST Client (Postman) by POSTing to API End Point

```
http://example.com/api/attachments/profile/upload
```

The image uploads but API is not responding it stop the server without log any error. 
And the Postman shows me **Could Not Get Any Response**.
When I'm doing the same on Localhost it working perfectly.

Please help me, I waste more than a week on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It was really a funny thing. After 8 months I find the issue.

I'm serving my NodeJS server using **pm2** with `--watch=true` option, whenever a file uploaded to `./uploads` the **pm2** observe the changes in the root directory and try to restart the server before the upload API response. That why the upload API never responded.

Now I added the `./uploads` directory to **pm2** ignore watch array, that resolves my issue.